# Read access violation when trying to compare int?

Tags: c, recursion, struct, tree, binary

I am getting a read access violation and I cant understand why. I though I allocated everything correctly and I shouldn't be reading past the end of anything? Any ideas or help is greatly appreciated.

I am trying to read in a file that has a single integer per line and store those into a binary tree and linked list. The tree actually holds the data and the linked list just holds pointers to the nodes in the tree.

The error happens in the `insert()` function when data and `node->num` are being compared.

The `newNode()` function creates both a tree node and a linked list node, it only returns the tree node because of the double pointer handling the linked list.

```
// Garrett Manley

// delete these when turning it in
#pragma warning(disable : 4996)

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// define structs
struct treeNode {
    int num;
    struct treeNode *right, *left;
};

struct listNode {
    struct treeNode *tNode; // data is a pointer to the tree
    struct listNode *next;
};

// creates and returns a new node with given data, also adds node to linked list 
struct treeNode *newNode(int data, struct listNode *(*list)) {
    // make tree node
    struct treeNode *node = malloc(sizeof(struct treeNode));
    node->num = data;
    node->left = NULL;
    node->right = NULL;
    // make list node
    // insert entry into linked list
    struct listNode *newNode;
    newNode = malloc(sizeof(struct listNode));
    newNode->tNode = node;
    newNode->next = *list;
    *list = newNode;

    return (node);
}

// inserts given node into the tree in sorted order
struct treeNode *insert(struct treeNode *node, int data, struct listNode *(*list)) {
    if (node == NULL) { // if the tree is empty return new node
        return (newNode(data, list));
    } else { // if there is a node use recursion to get to the bottom of the tree and add a node in the right spot
        if (data <= node->num) {
            node->left = insert(node->left, data, list);
        } else {
            node->right = insert(node->right, data, list);
        }
        return (node); // return the (unchanged) node pointer
    }
}

// print linked list by looping through list, keep looping until node.next == null
// while looping print like this node.data.data to get the tree nodes data
void printList(struct listNode *(*list)) {
    struct listNode *tmp = *list;
    while (tmp->next != NULL) {
        tmp = tmp->next;
        printf("here");
    }
}

// skim through the file and find how many entries there are
int SCAN(FILE (*stream)) {
    int size = 0;
    char *str = malloc(100 * sizeof(char));
    while (fgets(str, 100, stream) != NULL) {
        size++;
    }
    return size;
}

// loop through the file and load the entries into the main data array
void LOAD(FILE *stream, int size, struct treeNode *(*tree), struct listNode *(*list)) {

    rewind(stream);
    int i;
    char *tmp = malloc(100 * sizeof(char));
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        fgets(tmp, 100, stream);

        // recursively call insert to create the list, fix
        *tree = insert(*tree, atol(tmp), list);
    }
}

// free up everything
void FREE(struct treeNode *BlackBox, int size) {
    // free linked list first
    // then free the tree nodes, do this recursively
}

int main(int argv, char *argc[]) {

    FILE *file = fopen("./hw7.data", "r");

    int size = SCAN(file);

    struct treeNode *tree = malloc(size * sizeof(struct treeNode));
    struct listNode *list = malloc(size * sizeof(struct listNode));

    LOAD(file, size, &tree, &list);
    
    // print output

    // print linked list
    //printList(list);

    fclose(file);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How do I fix that?

Comment: sorry I got confused between treeNode and listNode

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to allocate memory in `main` for the tree, nodes are allocated by `insert` as needed.  Allocating uninitialized memory for `tree` and `list` causes undefined behavior when the members pointed to by these pointers are dereferenced.

Change the initializations to:

```
    struct treeNode *tree = NULL;
    struct listNode *list = NULL;
```

Also note that the parentheses in `return (node);` are unnecessary, it is customary to write `return node;` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Was allocating memory twice, removed malloc() in main() and now program works.